# bijection between $\mathbb{N}$ and $\mathbb{N}$×$\mathbb{N}$ that supports additivity

Tags: elementary-number-theory, elementary-set-theory

Is there a bijective function from $\mathbb{N}$ to $\mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N}$ and supports additivity? Namely if $n,m \in \mathbb{N}$ then:

$$f(n)+f(m)=f(n+m)$$

If there isn't, how can one prove such a thing?

Comment: Assume you had such a map. Let f(1) = (a,b) so f(m+1) = f(m) + (a,b). It should be easy to see that f(1) = 1*(a,b); f(n+1) = f(n) + (a,b) = (n+1)(a,b) and so f(n) = n(a,b). I.E. all the pairs are of the form (na,nb). What is left for you to show is that there are pairs not in the form (na,nb) Hint: Consider two cases, a = 1, and a ≠ 1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

any such map must have the form
$$
f(n)=n(a,b)
$$
where $(a,b)\in \mathbb{N}\times \mathbb{N}$,indeed,we can prove easily (by induction)that $\forall n\in \mathbb{N}:f(n)=nf(1)$ so $f$ is completely determined by its valus at $1$.So there is no surjective "additive" map between  $\mathbb{N}$ and $\mathbb{N}\times \mathbb{N}$, and in particular no bijective ones.